# How to compare 2 datasets in ADF dataflow and save the difference?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to compare 2 tables and filter rows that are not the same and mark the column value in which they are different.

TABLE 1

| User | Number | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | 1 | A | value2 |
| User1 | 2 | A | value3 |
| User1 | 1 | B | value4 |
| User1 | 2 | B | value5 |
| User1 | 1 | C | value6 |
| User1 | 2 | C | Value7 |
| User1 | 1 | D | Value8 |
| User1 | 2 | D | Value9 |

TABLE 2

| User | Number | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | 1 | A | value2 |
| **User1** | **2** | **B** | **value3** |
| User1 | 1 | B | value4 |
| User1 | 2 | B | value5 |
| **User1** | **1** | **A** | **value6** |
| User1 | 2 | C | Value7 |
| User1 | 1 | D | Value8 |
| **User1** | **2** | **A** | **Value9** |

The final table should look like this:

FINAL TABLE

| User | Number | Type | Value | Type Change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **User1** | **2** | **B** | **value3** | from A to B |
| **User1** | **1** | **A** | **value6** | from C to A |
| **User1** | **2** | **A** | **Value9** | from D to A |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join TABLE1 and TABLE2 first, then use filter to get the rows which's type isn't same. Next create a DerivedColumn to generate Type Change column. Finally, use Select transformation to remain the columns you need.

Details:

1. Create Join transformation to TABLE1 and TABLE2.

[image]

2. Filter the rows which's type isn't same. Expression:`source2@Type != source1@Type`

[image]

3. Add Type Change column. Expression:`concat('from ',source1@Type,' to ', source2@Type)`

[image]

4. Use Select transformation to remain the columns you need.

[image]

Data Preview:

[image]